# NGINX change phpMyAdmin port within a location block

Tags: php, linux, apache, nginx

I have my [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) setup as follows. This is within the server block of the default in sites-available and sites-enabled.

How can I change the port to say 8003 within the location block or somewhere without affecting the function of the port 80?

```
server{
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    [..........]

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            root /usr/share/;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
        }
    }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
           rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }

    [..........]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a port in a location block. It wouldn't make sense because the client is connected already when a location is processed. You can make a new server block though, listening on the port you want, and put the location-block in question in the new server block.

Comment: Listening on a different port isn't going to make it any more secure than changing the URL, which you can do if you want. Otherwise you can activate HTTP auth for that location: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule